# How to prevent Voice Over from reading unaffiliated HTML text (next div)?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, accessibility, wai-aria

I have an issue where drilling down into a text field with Control+Option+Shift+Down ends up reading more than what's currently inside of the text field. The Voice Over utility is concatenating an unaffiliated div, and I'm not sure if there's a way that I can specify a boundary. I don't want to read "Date Of Birth" when they're only editing the "Preferred Name" (see second screenshot)

[image: dom shows separate divs]

[image: voice over is reading more than just current div]

Comment: which voice reader are you using?

Comment: OSX with the CMD+F5 utility. The general thing is to use Up/Down with Shift sparingly, and mostly use Control+Option+Left or Right